# Cleaning up old HWE stacks?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I've been running 12.04 since release and have updated to every new HWE stack.

I am currently on 12.04.4.

Does anyone know how to clean out all the old versions of HWE? I currently have way too many kernels on my laptop, which becomes a pain when DKMS starts rebuilding modules.

If anyone has any advise, that would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Michael

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu). I personally use Ubuntu Tweak which also is mentioned in the accepted answer.